# what Integer.valueOf() returns in java?

Tags: java

Why

```
Integer.valueOf(1000) == Integer.valueOf(1000)
```

returns `false`, while

```
Integer.valueOf(6) == Integer.valueOf(6)
```

returns `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)):

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

Therefore, `Integer.valueOf(6)` has only one instance object while `Integer.valueOf(1000)` creates a new `Integer`.

Hence `Integer.valueOf(6) == Integer.valueOf(6)` and `Integer.valueOf(1000) != Integer.valueOf(1000)`

Answer (score 1):

Because some lower valued Integer objects are cached and reused. So all Integer objects of lower values, like 6, refer to the same Integer instance.